# HTML/PHP and CSS Pages not Linking

Tags: php, html, css

I have a basic webpage made up of a few PHP pages and a few CSS stylesheets.  One of these stylesheets is `style_common.css` which is used by all pages on the website to provide a constant theme.  I am having a bit of trouble with this file.   I currently have only 2 PHP pages which reference this common CSS file.

The home page (`index.php`) references the CSS file fine, and the stylesheet styles it as you would expect.  I copied the entire contents of `index.php` and pasted it into a second PHP file, then changed a few minor details such as the heading caption.  This new page however, doesn't link to the CSS stylesheet.

My code is below:

**style_common.css**:

```
body {
    background-color: #32BEED;
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>324 SQN Canteen Manager</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style_index.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style_common.css"/>
</head> 
<body>
<div class="header">
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="aafclogo">
    <h3> Canteen Manager</h3>
    <h6>Designed by Me</h6>
</div>
<div class="buttonContainer">
    <a href="addstock.php"><div class="button">
        <p>Add Stock</p>
    </div></a>

    <a href="sellitems.php"><div class="button">
        <p>Sell Items</p>
    </div></a>

    <a href="recordstocktake.php"><div class="button">
        <p>Record Stocktake</p>
    </div></a>
</div>
```

The second page which I copied from **index.php** and changed a few minor fields:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>324 SQN Canteen Manager</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style_index.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style_addstock.css"/>
</head> 
<body>
<div class="header">
    <img src="images/aafclogo.png" class="aafclogo">
    <h3>Add Stock</h3>
</div>
<div class="buttonContainer">
    <a href="index.php"><div class="button">
        <p>Home</p>
    </div></a>
</div>
```

Just to give you an example, the background colour of the second page is white, not the colour specified in the CSS file.

Where am I going wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any 404 errors in your developer console when loading the second file?

Comment: Use the browser debugger `F12` and check if the style sheets are being loaded.

Comment: Are the two pages not in the same directory? If so, you have to use the correct relative path for linking

Comment: The second page doesn't link to style_common.css. It links to style_addstock.css

Comment: if those css files aren't in the same folder as your other file(s), then that would explain it. If other files are outside the scope of those, well... there you go. Use error reporting.

Comment: oh for crying outloud, you're not using the right filename. **style_common.css** - **style_addstock.css** - your logs would have told you - 404 - use `file_exists()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: I can't apologise enough for this stupid question.  Obviously I just flicked the wrong link around to addstock.  Again, I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having the problem because you never linked

```
style_common.css
```

to the second page. Instead you have

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style_index.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style_addstock.css"/>
```

**FIX:**
add

```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style_common.css"/>
```

to the second page.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this stupid question.